# How to make Delphi XE2 look good on 4k monitor with 200% text size?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, highdpi

I have the new Dell XPS 15 Kaby Lake version with 3840x2160 resolution and text size set to 200%. Now, the Delphi XE2 looks terrible, some parts: 
[image] or [image]
I tried to set various settings via it's shortcut in Properties->Compatibility, I also tried to search the internet, but I only found that people care about the look of their applications, but our application looks well. Problem is only with the Delpi XE2 loooking so bad it's unusable on my laptop.

Any help how to easily fix it?

EDIT: I have Windows 10 installed.

Comment: Best to use a monitor with larger pixels.

Comment: Why is it downvoted? Should I add what everything I tried and what links I have open?

Comment: http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30367 helps in Seattle (it fixed the same sort of issue in the Tools->Options and Project->Options dialogs, as well as other locations). I see no reason it wouldn't work in XE2 as well.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, do I understand it correctly that the text will be smaller (but readable at least)? The perfect solution would be to let the text be small, but make more space for it, but it's maybe impossible...

Comment: Yes. I'm not certain how well it will work with 4K resolutions, but it will be at least readable, I think. It certainly will be much better than what you're seeing now. :-) And if it doesn't work, it's simply a unit you add to a package, so you can always just remove it to go back to what you've shown above.

Comment: Wow, I fixed it (and more nicely)! I will write an answer, but I still need to try something, before I write it.

Comment: @Ken White - you've provided the answer, so you should post the answer so Lukas can accept it.

Comment: I am very helpful for the help, but I fixed it differently in the end.

Comment: Just a word of warning. Running Delphi at a different DPI can have serious implications for how the applications built with Delphi run on other DPI's including standard 96 DPI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it without help from internet by trying various settings of the shortcut: 
[image: Properties]
[image: Compatibility]

It was needed to disable "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" and also to enable "Combatibility mode" and set it to "Windows XP (Service Pack 3)", both settings were needed together, the program loads very slowly now, but good enough and the GUI is displayed perfectly.